# Calculate confusion_matrix for Training set

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, knn

I am newbie in **Machine learning**. Recently, I have learnt how to calculate `confusion_matrix` for `Test set` of `KNN Classification`. But I do not know, how to calculate `confusion_matrix` for `Training set` of `KNN Classification`?

How can I compute `confusion_matrix` for `Training set` of `KNN Classification` from the following code ?

Following code is for computing `confusion_matrix` for `Test set` :

```
# Split test and train data
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = np.array(dataset.ix[:, 1:10])
y = np.array(dataset['benign_malignant'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

#Define Classifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred) # Calulate Confusion matrix for test set.
```

**For k-fold cross-validation:**

I am also trying to find `confusion_matrix` for `Training set` using `k-fold cross-validation`.

I am confused to this line `knn.fit(X_train, y_train)`.

Whether I will change this line  `knn.fit(X_train, y_train)` ?

Where should I change `following code` for computing `confusion_matrix` for `training set` ?

```
# Applying k-fold Method
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
kfold = 10 # no. of folds (better to have this at the start of the code)

skf = StratifiedKFold(y, kfold, random_state = 0)

# Stratified KFold: This first divides the data into k folds. Then it also makes sure that the distribution of the data in each fold follows the original input distribution 
# Note: in future versions of scikit.learn, this module will be fused with kfold

skfind = [None]*len(skf) # indices
cnt=0
for train_index in skf:
    skfind[cnt] = train_index
    cnt = cnt + 1

# skfind[i][0] -> train indices, skfind[i][1] -> test indices
# Supervised Classification with k-fold Cross Validation

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

conf_mat = np.zeros((2,2)) # Initializing the Confusion Matrix

n_neighbors = 1; # better to have this at the start of the code

# 10-fold Cross Validation


for i in range(kfold):
    train_indices = skfind[i][0]
    test_indices = skfind[i][1]

    clf = []
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2)
    X_train = X[train_indices]
    y_train = y[train_indices]
    X_test = X[test_indices]
    y_test = y[test_indices]

    # fit Training set
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train) 


    # predict Test data
    y_predcit_test = []
    y_predict_test = clf.predict(X_test) # output is labels and not indices

    # Compute confusion matrix
    cm = []
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_predict_test)
    print(cm)
    # conf_mat = conf_mat + cm
```

Comment: Hint: if you know how to compute `f(a)`, you know how to compute `f(b)`: just replace `a` by `b` in your function call...

Comment: I am confused to this line `knn.fit(X_train, y_train)`. Whether I will change this line ? @Julien

Comment: It depends what you want to do. If you just want to see the result with your current model (trained on training data) then you don't want to refit your model. If you want some sort of cross-validation (I doubt it, by the sound of your question) then you need to change it accordingly too.

Comment: Please see my edited question @Julien.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont have to make much changes

```
# Predicting the train set results
y_train_pred = knn.predict(X_train)
cm_train = confusion_matrix(y_train, y_train_pred)
```

Here instead of using `X_test` we use `X_train` for classification and then we produce a classification matrix using the predicted classes for the training dataset and the actual classes.

The idea behind a classification matrix is essentially to find out the number of classifications falling into four categories(if `y` is binary) -

1. predicted True but actually false
2. predicted True and actually True
3. predicted False but actually True
4. predicted False and actually False

So as long as you have two sets - predicted and actual, you can create the confusion matrix. All you got to do is predict the classes, and use the actual classes to get the confusion matrix.

**EDIT**

In the cross validation part, you can add a line `y_predict_train = clf.predict(X_train)` to calculate the confusion matrix for each iteration. You can do this because in the loop, you initialize the `clf` everytime which basically means reseting your model.

Also, in your code you are finding the confusion matrix each time but you are not storing it anywhere. At the end you'll be left with a cm of just the last test set.

Comment: Isn't need to change this line `knn.fit(X_train, y_train)` ? @ClockSlave

Comment: No. You don't have to change the line. In machine learning, we usually train the model on training dataset and predict on the test data. If you want to predict on the training data, you don't have to change the model.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. In a k-fold cross validation (2-fold here) you do exactly that. You switch test and train set and accumulate predictions to get an accumulated confusion matrix.

Comment: @stefan, yeah, I agree. Thats why I said usually and not always and the OP doesn't mention anything about cross validation. SO given the context, it was safe to say that.

Comment: In ML we usually do not predict training data. But we usually do cross validation. You want to extend your answer?

Comment: No. The question was about how to predict the confusion matrix for the training data and if the OP needed to change his model. Think about this use case itself. In that case, I think the answer is sufficient. We can keep discussing ML practices but that is in the scope of the function.

Comment: @stefan where did you get that "we" usually don't predict on training? I always predict on training too (and I doubt I'm alone in the ML community). How do you know if you are under or over fitting without comparing training and validation results?

Comment: @Julien, I can agree to that. I almost always predict on both the sets and check the difference between the accuracy metrics for each of them to get directions.

Comment: I have edited my answer. But I want to know, what is confusing you about using that line? What exactly are you thinking? Why are you uncomfortable with that line? We can discuss this in chat if needed.

Comment: I am applying `10-fold cross-validation`. I am not confirm whether above method is right or not. I am not clear about this line `clf.fit(X_train,y_train) `.  Both `confusion_matrix of test set` and `confusion_matrix of training set`, why this line `clf.fit(X_train,y_train) ` will unchange ? @ClockSlave

Comment: This may not be the most elegant method but its fine technically. That line remains unchanged because in the loop, for every time you assign to `X_train`, 'X_test', etc, you are also re-initializing the `clf` and creating a new instance of `KNeighborsClassifier `. The `fit` method doesn't have to be called again because, in machine learning we fit the model on training data and predict it on test data. This is done to test the goodness of fit of the model. We do this because we want to know if our model is good at predicting only the training data or test data as well.

Comment: To put it simply, assume the directions from your house to market is three lefts and a right. Assume thats your model. The model of three lefts and one right does your case very well. It is also a good model for your neighbor and so on. But  that wouldn't imply that it will be a good model for the house three blocks away. SO thats why we train the model on a particular set and check if it is able generalize its learning to predict for other cases which it hasn't seen before

Comment: Thanks a  lot @ClockSlave.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152753/discussion-between-md-rezwanul-haque-and-clock-slave).